# Dependency present in local repository but maven searching in remote repo

Tags: java, maven

I have a particular dependency defined in `POM.xml`. This is present in the local repository. However while running the command `mvn clean install` , I get the `missing artifact error`. When I delete the dependency from local and run the command, the same dependency gets copied in that path and still I get the same error

Comment: Can you share the artifact?

Comment: @leopal I cannot share it. Not permitted to share.Its an internal artifact

Comment: Could you please share the entire stacktrace. It is possible that the version getting resolved is not the right one.

Comment: @Ananthapadmanabhan, cannot share it, it has internal classes. The version getting printed in the stack trace is same as the one I have in the local repo

Comment: Could you please check to ensure that the stacktrace is not printing missing artifact for any transitive dependency ?

Comment: @Ananthapadmanabhan no not transitive dependency

Comment: Double check yougot correct artifactId packageId and those corresponds to what you have in .m2 location.

Comment: I would close this question. If all relevant information is confidential, then you need to hire a consultant, not go to stackoverflow.